# Sample parser code for the CEDICT

Tags: unicode, utf-8, dictionary, cjk

Does anyone have a sample code for parsing the CEDICT file? CEDICT is a Chinese-English Dictionary. For instance, currently, if I open it in a text editor, a line in the CEDICT file looks like:

‰∏ç ‰∏ç [bu4] /(negative prefix)/not/no/

I would like to see it as:

不 不 [bu4] /(negative prefix)/not/no/

I found Textwrangler to do this for me as a text editor. What I now need is sample code that achieves the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing is, it's just an encoding problem. If the line looks like

‰∏ç ‰∏ç [bu4] /(negative prefix)/not/no/

It's because the text editor doesn't know/realize that the text is encoded as UTF-8. Text Wrangler, or its big brother BBEdit, are very good at guessing encoding, and can even be asked to display text in a specific encoding.

Since we don't know what you want, in the end, to achieve, it's hard to tell you exactly what has to be done, specifically. What I can say is that your app (which language are you using anyway?) needs to be Unicode aware (and be able to read/manipulate UTF strings).

I wrote a couple of apps based on the CEDICT, one for Mac OS X, one for Android. Parsing and indexing the CEDICT is not very hard.

### UPDATE

Regarding the parsing itself of the CEDICT, it's nothing complicated. I don't do Objective-C, never have, never will, but the process would be the same in any language:

- Read a line. Say your own example: 不 不 [bu4] /(negative prefix)/not/no/
- You have four fields: Trad. Ch., Simp. Ch., Reading, Meaning(s).
  These fields are space separated. Of course the 4th field may contain spaces, so be careful.
- Store (I used an sqlite db) the 4 fields in to db.
  You might want to remove the slashes from the definition field, replace them with something else.
- Loop

You have now converted the CEDICT to a database. That's the easy part. As for tokenizing Chinese, good luck with that, mate. Better minds than mine are still banging their heads on this one.

Comment: Thanks so much dda. i am writing an iphone app which will translate chinese text (articles, emails, stories etc) to english with reasonable accuracy. Any sample code (say, how to tokenize a stream of Chinese characters into words, how to search for a given chinese word in CEDICT, etc) in Obective C will be good. Please note that I am developing a commercial app.

Comment: Thanks again dda. I am leaving the questions as unanswered for a few more days to see if anyone could give me any responses. This may interest you ... http://technology.chtsai.org/mmseg/